# Error al intentar convertir cadena binaria a entero: ValueError: invalid literal for int()

Tags: python, python-3.x, socket

Tengo el siguiente servidor que estoy tratando de realizar el problema surge que cuando el cliente pide al servidor el archivo y el servidor le responde. En el cliente sale el siguiente error:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Users\Angel\Desktop\cliente2.py", line 19, in <module>
>     while current_size < int(size):
> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:
> ```

Según entiendo el problema parece ser que no puede convertir `size` a entero
pero si lo dejo como bytes que es como viene me marca otro error y el cual es que no se pueden hacer operaciones entre bytes y enteros.

Les dejo los códigos, espero puedan ayudarme:

**CLIENTE**

```
import socket

conexion = ("Pc-1",900)
cliente = socket.socket()
cliente.connect(conexion)

while True:
    msg = input("> ")
    cliente.sendall(msg.encode())
    respuesta = cliente.recv(1024)
    print(respuesta.decode())

    if msg == "archivo":
        size = cliente.recv(1024)
        print(size)

        current_size = 0
        bufer = b""
        while current_size < int(size):
            print(int(size))
            data = cliente.recv(1024)
            if not data:
                break
            if len(data) + current_size<int(size):
                data = data[:int(size)-current_size]
            bufer += data
            current_size += len(data)
        with open("recibido.jpg","wb") as file:
            file.write(bufer)
```

**SERVIDOR**

```
import socket
import os

servidor = socket.socket()
conexion = (socket.gethostname(),900)
servidor.bind(conexion)
servidor.listen(1)

cliente,direccion = servidor.accept()

longitud = os.path.getsize("imagen.jpg")

while True:
    datos = cliente.recv(1024).decode()
    mensaje = input("> ")
    cliente.sendall(mensaje.encode())
    if datos == "exit":
        cliente.sendall("exit".encode())
        break
    elif datos == "archivo":
        cliente.send(bytes(longitud))

        with open("imagen.jpg","rb") as file:
            d = file.read(1024)
            while d:
                cliente.send(d)
                d = file.read(1024)
servidor.close()
```

Para poner un poco mas en contexto:

El cliente manda el mensaje archivo al servidor y el servidor si lee el mensaje archivo manda la longitud total del fichero a enviar a el cliente y posteriormente manda el archivo en blockes de 1024bytes.

Pero el cliente se queda sin hacer nada hasta que el servidor manda un mensaje entonces arroja el error de arriba.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que `bytes(int)` no hace lo que esperas. Lo que hace este código es **obtener un objeto bytes de la longitud determinada por el entero y lleno de bytes nulos**:

> ```
> >>> bytes(5)
> b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
> ```

Lo más simple que puedes hacer es usar una cadena para representar el entero y después codificarla:

> ```
> >>> longitud = 4
> >>> long_repr = str(longitud).encode("utf-8")
> >>> long_repr
> b'4'
> >>> int(long_repr)
> 4
> ```

Ten en cuenta que esto nada tiene que ver con obtener la representación binaria de un entero, lo cual también te serviría para tu caso. Para obtener la representación binaria de un entero tienes varias formas:

- Usar el módulo [`struct`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/struct.html):

  ```
  >>> import struct
  >>> longitud = 4

  >>> int_repr = struct.pack(">Q", longitud)
  >>> int_repr
  b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x04'
  >>> struct.unpack(">Q", int_repr)[0])
  4
  ```

  Al usar `Q`, el tamaño estándar es de 8 bytes, tipo `unsigned long long` en C. Esto nos permitiría almacenar como máximo el entero 18446744073709551615 (`b'\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff'`).

  `>` indica que se use big-endian.
- Usar `int.to_bytes` y `int.from_bytes`:

  ```
  >>> longitud = 4
  >>> int_repr = longitud.to_bytes(8, byteorder="big", signed=False)
  >>> int_repr
  b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x04'
  >>> int.from_bytes(int_repr, byteorder="big", signed=False)
  4
  ```

  En este caso, para ser congruentes con el ejemplo anterior se ha usado también 8 bytes y big-endian

Comment: me lanza un error de lado del cliente: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Angel\Desktop\cliente2.py", line 14, in <module>
    size = cliente.recv(1024).decode("utf-8")
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 7: invalid start byte`

Comment: El cliente manda el mensaje `archivo` al servidor y el servidor manda el archivo al cliente. pero el cliente se queda sin hacer nada hasta que el serivor le manda un mensaje cualquiera y lanza el error que menciono

Comment: a ya si mando el tamaño del fichero asi; long = str(longitud).encode("utf-8") lo que mando es la variable long desde el servidor al cliente y el cliente me da ese error

Comment: actualize los codigos para que puedas ver las modificaciones que realize

Comment: Lo que ahora lees como tamaño (`size = cliente.recv(1024)`) es parte del archivo en realidad, el tamaño llega en `respuesta = cliente.recv(1024)`. Te sobra una llamada a `recv` en el cliente, quita la línea `respuesta = cliente.recv(1024)` y el `print` que le sigue. . Además debe ser `longitud_rep = str(longitud).encode("utf-8")` no `longitud_rep = str(longitud).encode("ascii")`

Comment: si lo de la codificación lo cambie para ver si era eso pero vi que no era voy a cambiar lo que me acabas de señalar de `recv`

Comment: funciono gracias

Comment: De nada, he revertido la última edición de tu pregunta. Cuando edites actualizando la pregunta añadiendo nuevos errores producto de aplicar algo de una respuesta debes añadirlo a lo que ya tienes  al final de la pregunta, en caso contrario las respuestas y comentarios quedan fuera de contexto ya que el código que muestra tu pregunta no es el que produce el error original ya al que se dan respuestas. En este caso tu segundo problema era más bien un typo, eliminaste el input del server pero no eliminaste su recepción desde el cliente, por lo que solo he revertido la edición. Un saludo.